# Magento 2 - Add google captcha on contact form

Tags: magento2, contact-us, captcha

I want to add google captcha on contact us page.

copied

```
vendor/magento/module-contact/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/MyTheme/Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml
```

is there any simple widget to call google captcha on form.phtml?

Comment: What is your magento version?

Comment: I am using 2.2.5

Comment: https://www.mageknowledge.com/validate-google-captcha-via-javascript/

Comment: @Ghulam.M thanks for the link. I think that would work. Please add this in answer so that I can accept it after trying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose You have Form Similar to the code below

```
 <form id="myformId" class="col s12" action=""
       method="post"
      novalidate>
        <input placeholder="Name" id="mpfaqs-form-fieldset-input" type="text" name="username">
        <input placeholder="Email" id="mpfaqs-form-fieldset-input" type="text" name="useremail">
            <input placeholder="What is your question" id="mpfaqs-form-fieldset-input-question"
                   type="text" name="userquestion">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="YOURSITEKEYxxxxx"></div>
        <input class="form-submit" type="Submit" name="" value="Submit a question">
</form>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=es'></script>
```

To Validate above Form through javascript we will use the below code you can place it in the same file or create an external file for it and place the code

```
    <script>
    requirejs([
        'jquery'
    ], function($) {
        $(document).on('submit', '#myformId', function(){
            var isSubmit = jQuery(this).valid() && grecaptcha.getResponse() != '';
            if (!isSubmit) {
                alert("Please fill captcha");
            }
            return isSubmit;
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1 and accepted :)

Comment: Excellent and working very fine. +1

Comment: can you tell how to have invisible captcha for newsletter in magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

Magento has a default option for google captcha in contact us page.

> Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> CAPTCHA -> Choose Contact Us under Forms

[image: Refer the screenshot below]

Comment: is that google captcha?

Comment: Yes, it is. Magento has default option. Magento 2.3 version has google recaptcha

Comment: yes I have tried, but I don't think this is google captcha :) https://www.screencast.com/t/5nKBGA8d

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1 :)